# How to build Java JSONObject from JSON

Tags: java, json

How do I convert the following `JSON` into Java `JSONObject`?

```
{'my_hobbies': {'reading': {'book': {'genre': 'biography'},
                                     'book_data': {'authors': [{'name': 'Yarwood'}, {'name': 'Feukes'}]}}}}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is the definition of lack of effort.

Comment: Look for a *tutorial* or an *example*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

......

String jsonStr = "{'my_hobbies': ... }";
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

JSONObject = new JSONObject(jsonString)

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html